# Feature supported list for PayPal Rest API for non US

Tags: paypal

Looking forward for PayPal's new RestAPI.

We have already started building and finding cool things as we go. Since its an on going process of releasing features it is still not clear sometimes what is supported and what is not. I am listing down my doubts for **what is supported for Non-US developers**.

1. Merchants cannot accept payments by taking credit card number.
2. Subscription / recurring payment possible?
3. For Pay with PayPal method, does Paypal offer to accept payments form non Paypal users? Like pay directly using card on Paypal page?

Do mention if I missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

To register for a Live set of REST credentials you are required to provide:

```
U.S. Business owner Social Security Number, date of birth, and other personal details.
U.S. Business Tax ID (EIN, ITIN) and other business information.
```

Subscription / Recurring Payments are not yet available through the REST process. There are Reference Transactions allowed through "Vault" though.

There isn't an equivalent to "SOLUTIONTYPE" for the REST process yet but hopefully soon.